# How to generate OpenAPI specification (documentation.yaml) for all existing Ktor endpoints?

Tags: intellij-idea, documentation, openapi, endpoint, ktor

I have Ktor project with 100+ endpoints. How to generate documentation.yaml file with OpenAPI specifications for all existing endpoints? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.

I can't find any information about how to generate documentation.yaml file for all existing endpoints in a project.

Comment: Here (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ktor.html#openapi), you can find the information about OpenAPI specification generation.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. It doesn't generate anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the actions section of the search everywhere label to create OpenAPI documentation. Access to this label depends on your shortcut settings. It opens on double click for me. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UII6n.png)